# Prove that $f$ is injective if and only if, for every pair of subsets $A$ and $B$ in $X$, we have $f(A\backslash B)=f(A)\backslash f(B)$.

Tags: functions

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a function. Prove that $f$ is injective if and only if, for every pair of subsets $A$ and $B$ in $X$, we have $f(A\backslash B)=f(A)\backslash f(B)$.

The first part ($\Rightarrow$) I found easy to do. But the second part ($\Leftarrow$), all the ideas I had got me nowhere. For example, one of the ideas I had is making $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and try to prove that $x_1=x_2$. But I don't know how to start it. Should I separate in cases, like $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ belongs to $f(A)$ but not $f(B)$, and then the other cases...? I tried that but I got confused. The other way I tried is supposing and absurd that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ but $x_1\neq x_2$. And again I got stuck.

I am only asking here for a tip. Thanks.

Comment: The advantage of using the contrapositive approach is that $\lnot \forall$ becomes $\exists \lnot$, so you just need to find one particular $A,B$ counterexample given your $x_1,x_2$ counterexample.

Comment: In your example let $A = \{x_1,x_2\}$ and $B = \{x_1\}$  $f(A\setminus B) = f(\{x_2\})= \{f(x_2)\} = \{f(x_1)\}$.  But $f(A) = \{f(x_1),f(x_2)\} =  \{f(x_2)\} = \{f(x_1)\}$ whil $f(B) = f(\{x_1\})=\{f(x_1)\} = \{f(x_2)\}$. So $f(A)\setminus f(B) = \{f(x_1)\}\setminus \{f(x_1)\} =\emptyset$.  So $f(A\setminus B)=\{f(x_1)\}\ne \emptyset =f(A)\setminus f(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x\neq y$. Use $A = \{x,y\}$ and $B=\{y\}$.

Comment: Simple and easy. I did the contrapositive. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it enough to use $A=\{x\},B=\{y\}$, since $f(A\backslash B)=f(\{x\})=\{y\}$ and $f(A)\backslash f(B)=\{y\}\backslash \{y\}=\phi$?

Comment: Let $y\in f(A\setminus B)$. Then $y=f(x)$, $x\in A\setminus B$. So $y\in f(A)$. We need to show that $y\notin f(B)$. If $y\in f(B)$, then $y=f(x')$ for some $x'\in B$. Then $f(x')=y=f(x)$. Since $f$ is injective, $x=x'\in B$. This is a contradiction. Indeed, $y\in f(A)\setminus f(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose: for all $A,B \subset X$ that $f(A\setminus B) = f(A)\setminus f(B)$.

Let $x \in X$.

Let $A = f^{-1}(f(x)) = \{v \in X| f(v) = f(x)\}$ and let $B= \{x\}$

Note: $x \in A$ obvious, and if $f$ is injective that imply that $A = \{x\}$ and has no other elements.  That is what we will prove.

Then $f(A\setminus B) = \{f(v)| f(v)=f(x);v\ne x\}$.  If $f$ is injective this will be empty. And if this is not empty then  $f$ is not injective.

And $f(A) = \{f(v)|f(v)=f(x)\} = \{f(x)\}$.  And $f(B) =\{f(x)\}$.  So $f(A) \setminus f(B) = \emptyset$.

And that's that.  $f(A\setminus B)= f(A) \setminus f(B) = \emptyset$ so there is no $v\ne x$ so that $f(v) = f(x)$

and this is true for all $x\in X$ (and therefore for all $f(x) \in f(X)$) and $f$ is injective.